# How can I identify fields about to hit their max in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I had a table with an `INT(11)` error out after hitting `2147483647` today.

Is there a query I can run to find all at-risk fields?

Comment: Yes but you will have to write it

Comment: Maybe you should consider writing a purge when you have finished this query

Comment: @RiggsFolly, ha! Surely there's a programatic way of assessing field limits and MAX of the same field.

Comment: Yup thats what you have to write

Comment: you can query information_schema for details about tables to figure out which tables/fields you need to look at, but there's nowhere in mysql's queryable metadata that says what the limits are. that's implied by the field types, and what that type's limits are is buried internally in the code, and is otherwise only listed in the documentation. there's nowhere you can go in mysql to do `select MAX_SIZE(int), MAX_LENGTH(varchar)`-type queries.

Comment: Congratulations? That's highly unusual to see happen in practice unless the `AUTO_INCREMENT` has been manipulated manually. You'll need to pay attention to how many rows tables have if you're at risk of running out of ID values. `SHOW TABLE STATUS` and `SELECT MAX(id)` from each table will help inform. If you're storing that much data you might want to have a DBA on staff who can supervise your systems and anticipate problems like this.

Answer (score 2):

This should give you all current auto_increment values for the tables that have them:

`SELECT TABLE_NAME, AUTO_INCREMENT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE AUTO_INCREMENT IS NOT NULL;`

You can add something like `...AND AUTO_INCREMENT < 2147483637` to find all those that are within 10 of reaching limit, for example.

You can also be more specific about the database or table name if you'd like by including them in the `WHERE` clause. Try `DESC INFORMATION_SCHEMA` to see what fields you can use.